# Use laptop as primary monitor for desktop computer?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, desktop, pc

I currently have a computer running Windows 10. It has a ASUS® MAXIMUS VIII RANGER: RoG, PCI-e 3.0, SATA 3.0, LG1151 motherboard, integrated graphics.

I currently do not have an external monitor or keyboard for my computer, so I would like to use my laptop as a monitor for my computer. How would I do this and what cables or software would I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need an input on the laptop and an appropriate cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell us the laptop you have. Most of laptops actually do not have video input (I know that some lenovo and alienware does).

Besides, you have to solutions:

- The software one, that emulate a video input (such as Maxivista)
- The hardware one, which need an (expensive) device such a VGA2USB (https://www.epiphan.com/products/vga2usb/). (Note that such devices cost most of the time 200 to 300 € which leads me to say that it might be wiser to buy a monitor X) )

Since I never did that I can't tell for sure, but I think both solutions leeds to a latency that might be unsuitable for gaming.